# How one ViewModel contains multiple ViewModel xamatin

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have 2 ViewModels (MVVM). I let show 2 as shown, it only shows data 1 ViewModel (the one below).

I put 1 and it shows up as normal.

[image]

This is how I display the data

```
<RefreshView x:DataType="locals:SliderViewModel" 
             Command="{Binding LoadSliderCommand}" 
             IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}">
  <StackLayout Padding="8,0,8,4" 
               BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding SliderShowInfos}" 
               Orientation="Horizontal" 
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
      <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <StackLayout x:DataType="model:SliderShowInfo">
                  <Frame Padding="4" 
                         HasShadow="False" 
                         IsClippedToBounds="True" 
                         BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                          <Frame Padding="0" 
                                 HasShadow="False" 
                                 CornerRadius="7" 
                                 IsClippedToBounds="True">
                              <Image Source="{Binding ImagesSlider}">
                              </Image>
                          </Frame>
                      </StackLayout>
                  </Frame>
              </StackLayout>
          </DataTemplate>
      </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
  </StackLayout>
</RefreshView>

<RefreshView x:DataType="locals:ProductViewModel" 
             Command="{Binding LoadProductCommand}" 
             IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}">
  <StackLayout Padding="8" 
               Orientation="Horizontal" 
               BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ProductInfos}">
      <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <Frame Padding="5,0" 
                     HasShadow="False" 
                     IsClippedToBounds="True" 
                     BackgroundColor="#fff">
                  <StackLayout x:DataType="model:ProductInfo">
                  </StackLayout>
              </Frame>
          </DataTemplate>
      </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
  </StackLayout>
</RefreshView>
```

This is how I display the data. I'm trying to display product listing and photo listing data. Please give me a solution that can combine 2 ViewModel

**Update**

1. SliderViewModel.cs

   ```
    public class SliderViewModel:BaseSliderViewModel
    {
    ISliderShowRepository sliderShowRepository = new SliderShowService();
    public Command LoadSliderCommand { get; }
    public ObservableCollection<SliderShowInfo> SliderShowInfos { get; }
    public SliderViewModel()
    {
        LoadSliderCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadSliderCommand());
        SliderShowInfos = new ObservableCollection<SliderShowInfo>();
    }

    public void OnAppearing()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
    }

    async Task ExecuteLoadSliderCommand()
    {

    }
    }
   ```
2. ProductViewModel.cs

   ```
    public class ProductViewModel : BaseProductViewModel
    {
    IProductRepository productRepository = new ProductService();
    public  Command LoadProductCommand { get; }
    public ObservableCollection<ProductInfo> ProductInfos { get; }

    public Command ProductTappedView { get; }

    public ProductViewModel(INavigation _navigation)
    {
        LoadProductCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadProductCommand());
        ProductInfos = new ObservableCollection<ProductInfo>();

        ProductTappedView = new Command<ProductInfo>(OnViewDetailProduct);
        Navigation = _navigation;
    }
    private async void OnViewDetailProduct(ProductInfo prod)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailProduct(prod));
    }

    public void OnAppearing()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
    }

    async Task ExecuteLoadProductCommand()
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        try
        {
            ProductInfos.Clear();
            var prodList = await productRepository.GetProductsAsync();
            foreach (var prod in prodList)
            {
                ProductInfos.Add(prod);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
       }

      }
   ```
3. DashboardViewModel.cs

   public class DashboardViewModel
   {

   ```
    public SliderViewModel SliderShowVM { get; set; }

    public ProductViewModel ProductVM { get; set; }
   ```

   }

4. Dashboard.xaml.cs

   ```
    public Dashboard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true);
        BindingContext = new DashboardViewModel();
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
    }
   ```

Comment: first, please do NOT post code as images.  Second, you can't assign multiple values to `BindingContext`.  If your page needs data from two different VM, you need to create a wrapper VM class that contains both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant just have 2 ViewModels for a single page. Instead, you can create another ViewModel, which will contains those 2 ViewModels that you need.

```
public class DashboardViewModel
{
  public SliderShowViewModel SliderShowVM { get; set; }
  public ProductViewModel ProductVM { get; set; }
}
```

And in dashboard constructor, assign the BindingContext

```
BindingContext = new DashboardViewModel();
```

And in your view, bind data like this:

```
...
<Image Source="{Binding SliderShowVM.ImagesSlider}">
...
BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ProductVM.ProductInfos}"
...
```

---

Also, if you don't need all data from SliderShowViewModel or ProductViewModel on your Dashboard, then you can define the properties that you really need for the dashboard inside `DashboardViewModel`, and to inject `SliderShowViewModel` and `ProductViewModel` instances via constructor (Might not be the best solution, but this way you will keep you view cleaner)

```
public class DashboardViewModel
{
  public string RelevantProperty1 { get; set; }
  public int RelevantProperty2 { get; set; }
  ...

  public DashboardViewModel(SliderShowViewModel sliderVm, ProductViewModel productVm)
  {
    RelevantProperty1 = sliderVm.Something;
    RelevantProperty2 = productVm.SomethingElse;
    ...
  }
}
```

---

*More explicit*

1. DashboardViewModel class: It is a class with two properties of type `SliderShowViewModel` and `ProductViewModel`. These properties will store some instances (aka objects) of `SliderShowViewModel` and `ProductViewModel` respectively.
2. Create a DashboardViewModel instance and pass it as BindingContext for your Dashboard View:

   ```
    public Dashboard()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true);

       var viewModel = new DashboardViewModel();

       // Now we have the viewModel, but there is a problem.
       // Remember those two viewModels (SliderShowViewModel and ProductViewModel)?
       // Well, those properties are null, we have to provide values for them
       // before setting the binding context.
       viewModel.SliderViewModel = new SliderViewModel();
       viewModel.ProductViewModel = new ProductViewModel();

       BindingContext = viewModel;
    }
   ```
3. Bind values from DashboardViewModel on our View:

```
<RefreshView Command="{Binding SliderViewModel.LoadSliderCommand}" 
                IsRefreshing="{Binding SliderViewModel.IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}">
    <StackLayout Padding="8,0,8,4" 
                BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding SliderViewModel.SliderShowInfos}" 
                Orientation="Horizontal" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Frame Padding="4" 
                            HasShadow="False" 
                            IsClippedToBounds="True" 
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Frame Padding="0" 
                                    HasShadow="False" 
                                    CornerRadius="7" 
                                    IsClippedToBounds="True">
                                <Image Source="{Binding SliderViewModel.ImagesSlider}">
                                </Image>
                            </Frame>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </StackLayout>
</RefreshView>
<RefreshView Command="{Binding ProductViewModel.LoadProductCommand}" 
                IsRefreshing="{Binding ProductViewModel.IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}">
    <StackLayout Padding="8" 
                Orientation="Horizontal" 
                BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ProductViewModel.ProductInfos}">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Frame Padding="5,0" 
                    HasShadow="False" 
                    IsClippedToBounds="True" 
                    BackgroundColor="#fff">
                </Frame>
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </StackLayout>
</RefreshView>
```

Give it a try and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it

Comment: And yea, a friendly advice, don't insert code screenshots :) People on StackOverflow don't  agree this

Comment: I tried. However: <RefreshView x:DataType="locals:DashboardViewModel" Command="{Binding LoadSliderCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}">-->  Error XFC0045 Binding: Property "LoadSliderCommand" and IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}" not found

Comment: is `LoadSliderCommand` a property of DashboardViewModel or SliderShowViewModel? If your DashboardViewModel has a property of type SliderShowViewModel (called say ssvm), then, on the view, bind the command this way: `ssvm.LoadSliderCommand`. Point first to the SliderShowViewModel instance, then to it's property.

Comment: I've added: <RefreshView x:DataType="locals:DashboardViewModel" Command="{Binding LoadSliderCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}">
I have updated the classes. Can you just be more explicit. Thank you

Comment: Ok, I'll get back in 20-30 minutes or so with the "more explicit" version ;)

Comment: Thanks bro supported <3

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, Wait 30 minutes more, I'm very busy right now and can't edit the answer

Comment: Thanks for answering. You added "_" in var _viewModel = new DashboardViewModel(); ???. I changed: var _viewModel = new DashboardViewModel()----> var viewModel = new DashboardViewModel(). However the result is just null.
Class: DashboardViewModel{
         public SliderViewModel SliderViewModel { get; set; }
         public ProductViewModel ProductViewModel { get; set; }
} null result

Comment: oopsie, that was my mistake. It's `viewModel` now. But still, I don't get it. your viewModel is null? It can't be.

Comment: Yes, viewModel is null. Sorry I don't use github. I uploaded the Google Driver code, can you check it: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-Z9g81-uhck1myyp4KA3_SsWwz_ALh1_?usp=sharing. Thank you

Comment: Ok, lemme take a look :)

Comment: The project does not want to start, I got a bunch of unrelated errors. But still, try to remove all of your `x:DataType` from your refreshViews (might work). the viewModel can not be null, you're clearly instantiating it, I think the problem is with binding

Comment: I removed the x:DataType, however it still doesn't work, I'll try again. Thank you